# Visual Studio database project - altering table in pre-deployment doesn't work

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-2016

I need to alter a composite primary key for the table from the database project in Visual Studio 2017, namely change it to 2 columns instead of 4 after deleting all duplicates. I've put the script that deletes duplicates into pre-deploy, and it goes like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_table
(  
    <same columns as old_table>,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_NewPK] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Column1], [Column2] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO tmp_table 
    (SELECT <unique data from old_table>)

TRUNCATE old_table
DROP old_table

EXEC sp_rename 'tmp_table', 'old_table'
```

It works like charm, but the new old_table still has the old 4-column primary key after deployment, which isn't surprising because the code for old_table hasn't been altered. The problem is, when I try to edit old_table to have 2-column PK, the deployment fails with the

> SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider:
>   Msg 3728, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   'DF__old_table__' is not a constraint.

I presumed that code changes to tables are applied after pre-deploy scripts, but something looks terribly wrong with the order of events here, and I cannot see how to fix it.

Comment: Maybe the error Is from when you "edit old_table to have 2-column PK", you are using the wrong constraint name?

Comment: Not exactly, but I've found where it comes from. One of the columns I'm trying to remove from the primary key has a default constraint on it (with a random-ish name generated by SQL Server). When I change the primary key definition, the deployment script attempts to drop that default constraint AFTER the pre-deployment scripts were executed... so it doesn't exist anymore, because it has been created with a different random-ish name when I dropped and re-created the table. Interestingly, it also happens when I drop that default constraint explicitly during pre-deploy, so I'm stuck :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after re-reading [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gertd/2009/09/14/pre-deployment-scripts/) several times I realised what was wrong with the order of events here (yeah, the *pre-pre-deployment* stage problem) - that is, the deployment code is generated from the model comparison results, and the model comparison is done BEFORE executing pre-deployment code. So, it goes like this:

- Source and target database models are compared, the primary key change for the old_table is noted, and deployment script is modified to reflect that, including dropping the default constraint;
- Pre-deployment code is executed, and it alters old_table quite a bit, but deployment script doesn't know about that;
- Deployment code is executed, and promptly crashes on trying to drop that default constraint, because it's not there anymore (but it was there when we checked, only it isn't and shoulnd't even be... ugh);
- Profit (not really).

And yes, this is how it's supposed to work, and I was really missing something obvious. Now I know.

The solution for me was to create that DF__old_table__ constraint at the END of pre-deployment script, so it still exists in the altered old_table when deployment code comes looking for it, but then it's going to disappear because deployment code for the old_table doesn't have any defaults, and even if it did, the constraint would have a different name (because unnamed constraints are evil).

Speaking of which, this solution isn't 100% reliable because an unnamed constraint isn't guaranteed to have the same randomly generated name on your dev machine and on production server. And it's hacky. But it works for our setup, and any alternatives I could come up with were even hackier.